# Avoid stereo mixing: keep right track on Right Speaker only and Left on Left Speaker only

Tags: audio

My recording has 2 tracks.  I want to hear the left track only in the left ear and the right track only in the right ear. For some reason I hear both tracks in both ears. While on audacity when I mute the left track there is no left audio in my left or right ear but when I un-mute it is in both ears also when I mute the right track there is no right audio but when I un-mute it it is in both ears. The left track was recorded/played with L/R audio at 100% L and the right track was recorded/played with L/R at 100% R.  I hope it is something stupid on my part but I am at a loss as to what to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PC not differentiating Left/Right channel properly](https://superuser.com/questions/1118839/pc-not-differentiating-left-right-channel-properly)

Answer (score 0):

With audacity on a PC creating the wav or mp3 file with channel mode = stereo will write each of 2 tracks exactly as configured: the right track R=100% L=0% and the left track R=0% and L=100% giving exactly the result I was looking for.  On a MAC the the 2nd track is contaminated with audio from the first track.